# Mariadb query time extremely increased after upgrade from 10.2 to 10.4

Tags: optimization, mariadb, query, upgrade

After upgrading from Mariadb 10.2 to 10.4 extremely increased query time.

On 10.2 query time is 0.5s.

On 10.4 query time is 14s.
Also query plan has changed too.

10.2:

```
    -------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table       | type        | possible_keys                                    | key                             | key_len | ref                             | rows | Extra                                                         |
+------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2> | ALL         | distinct_key                                     | NULL                            | NULL    | NULL                            | 6938 | Using temporary; Using filesort                               |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | a4          | eq_ref      | PRIMARY,category_id_idx                          | PRIMARY                         | 8       | production.ptpv.product_id,const |    1 | Using index                                                   |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | a           | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                          | PRIMARY                         | 4       | production.ptpv.product_id       |    1 | Using where                                                   |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | a2          | ref         | PRIMARY,category_id_idx                          | PRIMARY                         | 4       | production.ptpv.product_id       |    1 | Using index                                                   |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | t           | ref         | product_option_value_id_idx,sup_id_idx,is_active | product_option_value_id_idx     | 5       | production.ptpv.product_id       |    6 | Using where                                                   |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | t2          | eq_ref      | PRIMARY,tbl_sup_type_idx                         | PRIMARY                         | 8       | production.t.sup_id              |    1 | Using where                                                   |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | a3          | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                          | PRIMARY                         | 4       | production.a2.category_id        |    1 |                                                               |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | ptpv        | index_merge | param_id_idx,param_value_id_idx,product_id_idx   | param_id_idx,param_value_id_idx | 152,606 | NULL                            | 9250 | Using intersect(param_id_idx,param_value_id_idx); Using where |
```

10.4

```
    +------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table       | type        | possible_keys                                    | key                             | key_len | ref                             | rows | Extra                                                         |
+------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2> | ALL         | distinct_key                                     | NULL                            | NULL    | NULL                            | 8404 | Using temporary; Using filesort                               |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | t           | ref         | product_option_value_id_idx,sup_id_idx,is_active | product_option_value_id_idx     | 5       | production.ptpv.product_id       | 11   | Using where                                                   |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | a4          | eq_ref      | PRIMARY,category_id_idx                          | PRIMARY                         | 8       | production.ptpv.product_id,const | 1    | Using index                                                   |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | a           | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                          | PRIMARY                         | 4       | production.ptpv.product_id       | 1    | Using where                                                   |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | a2          | ref         | PRIMARY,category_id_idx                          | PRIMARY                         | 4       | production.ptpv.product_id       | 1    | Using index                                                   |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | t2          | ALL         | PRIMARY,tbl_sup_type_idx                         | NULL                            | NULL    | NULL                            | 8978 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)               |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | a3          | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                          | PRIMARY                         | 4       | production.a2.category_id        | 1    |                                                               |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | ptpv        | index_merge | param_id_idx,param_value_id_idx,product_id_idx   | param_id_idx,param_value_id_idx | 152,606 | NULL                            | 8404 | Using intersect(param_id_idx,param_value_id_idx); Using where |
+------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is it possible to return to previous query plan ?

optimizer_switch has default values on both servers.

Comment: You MUST show query text! *Is it possible to return to previous query plan?* Try to renew tables' statistic. If this cannot help try to use STRAIGHT_JOIN and FORCE INDEX.

Comment: Ehm... I will not change the query anyway, it's generated by ORM. I need to know difference between query optimizer configuration for both versions. Query won't help to investigate the query time problems

Comment: In your previous configuration, you probably had `block_nested_loop` turned `off`; which seems like has been overridden after upgrade. Try disabling it. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/46372518/2469308

Comment: "Diff between optimizers"?  That would involve more space than this forum allows.  As for the "optimizer configuration" -- Well, that assumes that all the differences are exposed to configuration, which I seriously doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost always `index merge intersect` can be improved on by using a composite index.  Adding an index can be done without dealing with the ORM.